# Variable substitution in a for-loop using {$var}

Tags: bash

I'm very new to bash scripting and I'm trying to practice by making this little script that simply asks for a range of numbers. I would enter ex. 5..20 and it should print the range, however - it just echo's back whatever I enter ("5..20" in this example) and does not expand the variable. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Script:**

```
    echo -n "Enter range of number to display using 0..10 format: "
    read range

    function func_printrage
    {
         for n in {$range}; do
         echo $n
         done
    }

func_printrange
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Brace expansion in bash does not expand parameters (unlike zsh)
2. You can get around this through the use of `eval` and command substitution `$()`
3. `eval` is evil because you need to sanitize your input otherwise people can enter ranges like `rm -rf /;` and `eval` will run that
4. Don't use the `function` keyword, it is not POSIX and has been deprecated
5. use `read`'s `-p` flag instead of echo

However, for learning purposes, this is how you would do it:

```
read -p "Enter range of number to display using 0..10 format: " range

func_printrange()
{
  for n in $(eval echo {$range}); do
    echo $n
  done
}

func_printrange
```

*Note:* In this case the use of `eval` is OK because you are only `echo`'ing the range

Comment: Thank You, it works now! What is wrong with using "function" ? Is there an alternative I should be using?

Comment: @ZDRuX: `function` is not POSIX, i.e. it is not *portable*. As for the alternative see my code.

Comment: This use of eval is absolutely not safe. Try entering `1..5 $(ls)`.

Answer (score 7):

One way is to use `eval`, 
crude example,

```
for i in $(eval echo {0..$range}); do echo $i; done
```

the other way is to use bash's C style `for` loop

```
for((i=1;i<=20;i++))
do
  ...
done
```

And the last one is more faster than first (for example if you have $range > 1 000 000)

Comment: you cannot substitute variable in this way: `...;i<=$var;...`

Comment: @karatedog Correct, but you didn't really help.  The proper usage is to use the variable name without the `$` prefix: `for ((i=begin;i<=end;i++); do echo $i; done`

Answer (score 6):

One way to get around the lack of expansion, and skip the issues with eval is to use command substitution and seq.

Reworked function (also avoids globals):

```
function func_print_range
{
     for n in $(seq $1 $2); do
     echo $n
     done
}

func_print_range $start $end
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `${}` for variable expansion. In your case, it would be ${range}. You left off the $ in ${}, which is used for variable expansion and substitution.

Comment: Thank You for your comment, however - I do not want to execute a command in the subshell. I want to substitute the $range variable into the "for n in" loop, so essentially it becomes:  "for n in {5..20}; do"

Comment: @ZDRuX ah, I see, corrected my answer. You forgot the $ to initiate variable expansion.

Comment: -1, this does not answer the question. He is talking about *brace expansion* not *variable expansion*