# Looping through variable with spaces

Tags: bash

This piece of code works as expected:

```
for var in a 'b c' d; 
do 
    echo $var; 
done
```

The bash script loops through 3 arguments printing

```
a
b c
d
```

However, if this string is read in via jq , and then looped over like so:

```
JSON_FILE=path/to/jsonfile.json
ARGUMENTS=$(jq -r '.arguments' "${JSON_FILE}")

for var in ${ARGUMENTS};
do 
    echo $var; 
done
```

The result is 4 arguments as follows:

```
a
'b
c'
d
```

Example json file for reference:

```
{
    "arguments" : "a 'b c' d"
}
```

What is the reason for this? I tried putting quotes around the variable like suggested in other SO answers but that caused everything to just be handled as 1 argument.

What can I do to get the behavior of the first case (3 arguments)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable substitution in a for-loop using {$var}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447302/variable-substitution-in-a-for-loop-using-var)

Comment: This has nothing to do with jq, it's strictly a shell issue.

Comment: You might be able to use `xargs` to parse the quoted strings (see my answer to the superuser question ["Get bash to respect quotes when word splitting subshell output"](https://superuser.com/questions/1529226/get-bash-to-respect-quotes-when-word-splitting-subshell-output/1529316)) (provided the quoting/escaping in the string matches `xargs`' syntax). This may be tricky to implement, depending on what's actually in the `while` loop, but at worst you should be able to parse it into a bash array, then loop over that with `for var in "${arrayvar[@]}"`.

Comment: If you want to use jq, consider changing the format of your arguments to an array then output the array contents to a while loop. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950596/iterating-through-json-array-in-shell-script

Comment: The Q seems a bit muddled.  Having a JSON string like "a 'b c' d" seems improbable, but if that's what you really have, you would either have to parse it in jq according to your requirements (what are they?), or pass it to some external program to parse.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the reason for this?

The [word splitting expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting) is run over **unquoted** results of other expansions. Because `${ARGUMENTS}` expansion in `for var in ${ARGUMENTS};` is unquoted, word splitting is performed. No, word splitting ignores quotes resulted from variable expansion - it only cares about whitespaces.

> What can I do to get the behavior of the first case (3 arguments)?

The *good way™* would be to write your own parser, to parse the quotes inside the strings and split the argument depending on the quotes.

I advise to use `xargs`, it (by default, usually a confusing behavior) parses quotes in the input strings:

```
$ arguments="a 'b c' d"
$ echo "${arguments}" | xargs -n1 echo 
a
b c
d
# convert to array
$ readarray -d '' arr < <(<<<"${arguments}" xargs printf "%s\0")
```

As presented in the other answer, you may use `eval`, but please do not, [eval is evil](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) and will run expansions over the input string.

Comment: `-n1` is not needed for `xargs`

Comment: `-t` is not needed for `readarray` which is an alias for [mapfile](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/mapfileh.html)

Comment: Indeed, in this case `-t` is not needed.

Comment: `xargs` needs `-r` to fix the case `arguments=""` where `arr` should be `arr=()` not `arr=("")`

Answer (score -1):

Change IFS to a new line to make it work:

```
...
IFS='\n'; for var in $ARGUMENTS;
do 
    echo $var; 
done
```